# Is there a FIFO Queue which offers uniqueness based on some criteria

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures

I am using Java. I need to publish data to a FIFO queue. This queue will be processed by a separate thread. This way I avoid blocking the main thread.
My use case regarding publishing data is:-

- Each data object has a field, which identifies it uniquely.. so there are 50 odd such 'keys'. There are other fields which is rest of the data of the object.
- If a new data object comes along, it should not be blindly inserted in queue, but should replace old one.. **only** if their data is different based on field comparison etc.. otherwise it will be simply discarded. Remember, one of the field is the key.. rest are data and can wildly differ.
- These data must be processed on FIFO basis.. thus I need a queue kind of.
- Needless to say, it should be thread safe too.

Anyone knows any data structure that satisfies these criteria? Thanks.

Comment: if an update should replace an existing entry, does the new one go in the old one's spot in the queue, or does the old one get dropped from the queue and the new one get added at the end?

Comment: also, what kind of concurrency performance do you expect?

Comment: since you have at most 50 elements in your queue, you could most likely get away with a simple list wrapper in some synchronized blocks.  unless you require an extreme level of concurrency.

Comment: Replace existing one is better. Concurrency.. well must be sure that latest data must be available immediately for publish.. being financial kind of implications. But I agree size is quite small.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do something like this in C#, I created a custom data structure that contained a Dictionary and a Queue. The Dictionary was indexed by the item key, and the value contained the data associated with the key. The queue contained only the keys.

To insert an item into the queue, I did the following (pseudocode)

```
lock the data structure
    if key exists in dictionary
        replace old item data in dictionary with new item data
    else
        add new item to the dictionary, indexed by key
        add new item key to the queue
release lock
```

To dequeue an item:

```
lock
    remove first item key from queue
    lookup data for that key in dictionary
    remove item from dictionary
release lock
process the item
```

We did thousands of updates a second across multiple threads, and didn't encounter any performance problems. The locks just aren't held for very long. Your mileage may vary, of course.

You can avoid locks on the main thread by adding a lock-free concurrent queue that the main thread can push updates to. Another thread can service that queue and add items to the hybrid dictionary/queue structure I described above.